# Order shows no line items for Bundled Product

Tags: orders, ce-1.9.1.0, invoice, bundled-product

I have a bundled product with 3 associated Bundle Items:

[image]

When a customer makes their 3 choices and places an order, the line items for each choice don't show up in the Magento Orders admin page. I checked the rendered HTML and no rows are rendered in the body of this table for Items Ordered, only the table header with the column headings:

[image]

The line items do however show up if you then click on the Invoice button:

[image]

Line items show up correctly for simple products and configurable products. Does anyone know what is causing the line items to not show?

**Updated:**

We are using the Amasty Pre-order extension and it seems to be this which is causing the bundled products to not show in the Order line items. https://amasty.com/magento-pre-order.html

The line items table is rendered using this code:

```
        <tbody class="DANIEL <?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
            <?php Mage::log('++ Admin>Sales>Order>View>Items.phtml', null, 'crocodile.log', true) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
        </tbody>
```

In the rendered HTML we see the "DANIEL" class on the  but not inner html.

getItemHtml is from Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php

```
public function getItemHtml(Varien_Object $item)
{
    if ($item->getOrderItem()) {
        $type = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductType();
    } else {
        $type = $item->getProductType();
    }
    //return $this->getItemRenderer($type)
    //    ->setItem($item)
    //    ->setCanEditQty($this->canEditQty())
    //    ->toHtml();

    $renderer = $this->getItemRenderer($type)
        ->setItem($item)
        ->setCanEditQty($this->canEditQty());
    Mage::log('get_class(renderer): '.get_class($renderer), null, 'mylog.log', true);
    return $renderer->toHtml();
```

The log shows that the renderer is of type Amasty_Preorder_Block_Rewrite_Bundle_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Items_Renderer and calling toHtml returns a blank string:

```
get_class(renderer): Amasty_Preorder_Block_Rewrite_Bundle_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Items_Renderer
```

This returns a blank string:

```
var $theHtml = $renderer->toHtml();
```

Comment: Do you use any extensions related to product types?

Comment: We're using a Frequently Bought Together extension but most of the extensions we use aren't related to product types.

Comment: We are using the Amasty Pre-order extension which seems to be causing the issue. I've updated the question.

Comment: Why not ask Amasty?

Comment: I have asked Amasty, no response so far.